# Is it possible to reconcile forecasts that are not only at different levels of an organizational hierarchy, but also measured in different units?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

Consider the following scenario:

- I have a top line revenue forecasts in dollars for each of my corporate divisions or business units.
- I have capacity forecasts for each of my regional manufacturing and distribution centers, measured in resource utilization (labor shifts × resources needed × ...)
- I have unit demand forecasts, measured in number of units sold per product category/sales location.

I would like to reconcile these forecasts using an [optimal reconciliation approach](https://otexts.com/fpp2/reconciliation.html), but how do I do that given that these forecasts are not described in the same units of measure?

Simply using a multiplicative constant (e.g. taking an average unit retail $ and multiplying it by the sum of all units for the whole division) seems a little bit too simplistic. Is there a better approach?

Comment: +1. In a similar matter I expressed all the series in a common unit system before doing the forecasts. It depends on your application, for example, if one series is in US dollars and another in pound sterling, based on historical data we can transform one to another "historically" and then perform forecasting and forecast reconciliation. Raw manufacturing numbers do not directly translate to revenue of course but the main idea is to treat the multiplicative constant as being part of what is forecasted too.